# How to break conversation when sending another command

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telethon, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm using PyTelegramApi library. 
My bot has 4 buttons that each do a different action. 
How can I break the conversation when the user click on "back" button or send another command? 
For exmple: 
/start -> *click on new post button*. 
**Bot:** Hi, send text for the post. 
**User:** *Press back button and click on uplade photo button photo*. 
**Bot:** Hi, send your photo. 
**User:** send photo.. 
**Bot:** it's not text, try again (because he click on new post before) + **Bot:** Nice photo! 

How can I fix that thing?

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I didn't becaude I don't know, I would love to get some help..

Answer (score 0):

Just check what is the message text that user sent.

```
if message.text == "Back":
  # Sending a message to user like 'You are in MainMenu now.'
else:
  # ...
```